# Some USB devices will automatically reconnect after I unbind it, how to disable it long time?

Tags: linux, usb, keyboard, sysfs

I'm trying to disable my two USB keyboard on my linux system, the first one can unbind long time until I unplug then plugin and the number lock light is off during this time. But the other one can not unbind long time, maybe after 5 seconds, it will reconnect again and the number lock light is on during this time, the other lights will flash once, the log shown below:

```
[505545.210490] usb 3-3.1: USB disconnect, device number 47
[505547.687005] usb 3-3.1: new low-speed USB device number 49 using xhci_hcd
[505547.984255] usb 3-3.1: New USB device found, idVendor=17ef, idProduct=6099
[505547.984258] usb 3-3.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[505547.984260] usb 3-3.1: Product: Lenovo Traditional USB Keyboard
[505548.019948] input: Lenovo Traditional USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/0000:03:00.0/usb3/3-3/3-3.1/3-3.1:1.0/input/input40
[505548.071999] hid-generic 0003:17EF:6099.002A: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Lenovo Traditional USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:03:00.0-3.1/input0
```

Below is my shell command to disable the keyboard:

```
echo "3-3.1"  > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
```

or

```
echo "0003:17EF:6099.002A" > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-generic/unbind
```

What is the reason for this difference? Is there a way to disable the second keyboard for a longer time?